# Lightest and heavy coin among n coins using median scale

Tags: algorithm, median, divide-and-conquer

Suppose there is a median scale which takes an input of three coins and returns the median among three coins, it won't tell anything about the rest of two coins. How can we find the lightest and heaviest among the coins using O(nlgn).Provided there are n distinct coins.

Comment: Can the scale weigh only exactly 3 coins, or can I also make 3 groups of multiple coins and weigh those?

Comment: The scale will only return the _weigth_, but we won't know _which coin_ has that weigth, right? And of course we cannot put the _same coin_ twice (or thrice) in the same weighing?

Comment: Yes, it only takes three-coin at any time. And it returns the median coin.

Comment: Any additional condition, such as *each coin has a unique weight*, *weights are too close to judge without the scale* or *there is at most one coin with the same weight as either the lightest or the heaviest coin*?

Answer (score 1):

The lightest and heaviest coins are the only ones that aren't the median of any group.

Pick any 3 coins and discard the median. Repeat until there are only 2 left.

Since each operation discards a coin, this takes O(n) time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense...thank you .